# Select Node variables LISTEN and SERVER through a docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, coreos

I need to exectue my Node.js server with this command

```
node server.js LISTEN="0.0.0.0" SERVER="server.com" PORT=3000
```

But I have my server in a CoreOS cluster, and I use Docker to use a container but I don't know how to select this variables in the Dockerfile.

I set this

CMD [/usr/bin/nodejs /src/server.js LISTEN='0.0.0.0' SERVER='piggate.com'"]

But I have errors when I launch the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodejs env variables should be before the node command.

Try one of these:

`CMD LISTEN=0.0.0.0 SERVER=piggate.com /usr/bin/nodejs /src/server.js`

or

`ENV LISTEN=0.0.0.0 SERVER=piggate.com
 CMD /usr/bin/nodejs /src/server.js`

Comment: AFAIK you can't set multiple variables that way (on your `ENV` line), you need to use `<key>=<value>` format (`ENV LISTEN=0.0.0.0 SERVER=piggate.com`)